# win32security.LookupAccountName fails with error The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed

Tags: python, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domainservices

I have very basic question here...

I have a situation where friend of mine claims that he has a parent child domains created. As they are parent child domains there is two way transitive trust created by default...

But when I try to run Python application which internally calls win32security.LookupAccountName("", LocalSystem), it is taking approx. 2 minutes to complete and fails with exception "The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed " - Error Code -1788

Any idea what could have happened ? And how to resolve this ?
Is there any way to verify the trust relationship between these domains ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have seen that error before it has normally just required the machine in question to be removed from the domain and joined back to it again. So if it just one computer then I would suggest trying that first of all.